# Facebook API: Endless redirect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going crazy with the following code:

```
<?php
//Code of http://example.com/facebook/

require_once("../settings.php"); //Providing some settings
function authorize()
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".urlencode($GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]["appId"])."&redirect_uri=".urlencode("http://example.com/facebook/".(isset($_GET["delete"])?'?delete':''))."&scope=read_mailbox,offline_access");
    exit();
}

require_once("SDK/facebook.php");


if(!isset($_GET["code"]))
{
    authorize();
}

$facebook = new Facebook($GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]); //$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"] is defined and set correctly
$user=$facebook->getUser(); //retreive User ID
if(!$user)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    $LoginURL=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$LoginURL); //Endless redirect here
    exit();
}
?>
```

My problem is that `$user` always remains `0` and so the client is infinitely redirected. But I don't see a reason why `$user` always stays `0`. Normally it should be the user id of the currently logged in facebook user.

EDIT: `$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]` is set in `settings.php` like this:

```
$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"] = array();
$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]['appId'] = 'appID'; //appID replaced
$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]['secret'] = 'appSecret'; //appSecret replaced
$GLOBALS["FacebookConfig"]['fileUpload'] = false;
```

Comment: What does $facebook -> getUser() equate to during runtime?

Comment: `$facebook->getUser()` is constantly equal to `0`, that's exactly what I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code in my `settings.php` caused the error:

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*10);
```

As I did not know that this could affect the Facebook API, I did not comment it out. After removing it, it works perfectly fine. But it cost me some hours to find out...